# WIll CSS active work on a non-link element

Tags: css

I want a items that have the tag class to be grayed (with a rounded border) when the mouse moves over and when the item(s) are clicked.

A sample item might look like this `<span class="tag">Some value</span>`

I was hoping this would give the desired result, (tag:hover works as hoped, but tag:active doesn't):

```
.tag{
    }

.tag:hover{
    background:#CCC;
    padding:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;     
}

.tag:active{
    background:#CCC;
    padding:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;         
    }
```

Comment: Did you test it? http://jsfiddle.net/r4gQQ/ Seems to work for me.

Comment: Yep, I've tested it. Will take a look at your jsfiddle now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to permanently add a class to your `span`. You could do it like this:

```
.tag:hover, .tag.everclicked{
background:#CCC;
padding:4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;         
}
```

And in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.tag').click(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('everclicked');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4gQQ/2/

Comment: Thanks I should have been more clear. I know about how to do it with jQuery. From what I read CSS sounded like a cleaner way of achieving the same thing. Will do what you've suggested.

Comment: @Ankur: you *can* do it with pure CSS, but unfortunately not in IE 8 and lower - http://jsfiddle.net/r4gQQ/3/.

Comment: Yes I believe that a first solution with CSS will always be better, but this behavior is defined as whatever you want it. CSS cannot decide for you if you want this style: if you ever clicked, or if you toggle clicking, or whatever behavior you could think of. CSS only looks at local behavior like hovering and focusing, but not to global selection and definitely not time-depending. All of these hover events can be "undone" by deselecting or "dehovering".

Comment: @AndyE Nice example of using the `:checked` element, but now you can also deselect it again. So maybe this is not the full behavior that is wanted by OP. Probably it is though. =)

Comment: That hidden checkbox technique is epic win.  My first thought is you can use it to make it easy to fully style a checkbox without resorting to JS by hiding it and having its state affect some other related element instead.  Must remember that one.

Answer (score 2):

You have the same CSS styles defined for both pseudo-classes.  An `:active` element will usually have `:hover` too (depending on the browser), as it is applied whilst the mouse button is down on the element.

If you want the styles to stay applied when you've clicked and moved away from the element, you'll need to use JavaScript or, alternatively, give the element a `tabindex` attribute and use the `:focus` pseudo-class.  Using @Marnix's test case, for example, http://jsfiddle.net/r4gQQ/1/.

Comment: I was hoping that it would apply the class permanently once it was clicked, not just while being clicked - that's where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Ah so that was your intention... Didn't get that from your question. Maybe you should use jQuery to add an extra class on click.

Comment: The "active" state only lasts for the duration of the user's click.  If you want the style to persist longer than this, then you should probably attach a class to the clicked element with javascript and style that instead.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, the CSS for your :hover and :active states is identical, so you'll not see any change!

According to the specs for CSS on w3.org, :active used to only apply to hyperlinks in CSS1, but that's no longer the case.  I couldn't find any explicit statement regarding what elements it works for now, so I'm just going to assume it works everywhere unless someone else knows better.  It could be that it still only applies to elements the user is meant to "activate" by clicking, such as links and form buttons.

If :active does indeed apply to any kind of element now, then the above CSS should work as you want, provided you change the :active style to be different from the :hover style of course!

If it doesn't, then either there are still restrictions in CSS as to where you can use hover, or there's a bug in the CSS engine of your browser that restricts where you can apply the :active style in a way that goes against the current CSS specs.  If the latter is the case, then you could use javascript to add a class on mousedown to the clicked element and remove it again on mouseup or mouseout.  You can then style the active class in CSS as normal.